# What parameters do the front facing cameras support on Android phones

Tags: android, parameters, camera

Realizing that it's dependent upon the manufacturer, there are some settings that seem to be consistent across devices such as IOS, White Balance, exposure, etc...

I'm most interested in finding out if I can actually adjust things like:

ISO & White Balance

on the front facing cameras.  So far it appears not.

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

Comment: thanks but does list of parameters apply globally to both the front and rear sensors?  I didn't think it did (maybe it does...confirmation would be helpful if someone knows)

Comment: That will depend upon the hardware. Use `Camera.Parameters` and methods like `getSupportedWhiteBalances()` to find out what the capabilities are at runtime, and adapt accordingly.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Thank you.  So if I switch the camera to the front by selecting it, are you saying that the "getSupportedXXXXX()" methods will return differently based on front and rear?

Comment: Sure. You get the `Camera.Parameters` for a specific camera ID. The values will be based on the capabilities of that specific camera. For example, supported preview and pictures sizes usually vary significantly between the front and rear cameras. Note that `Camera.Parameters` is for the original camera API; there is an equivalent for `android.hardware.camera2`.